# Как сделать, чтобы обрабатывалось пока не пройдёт ошибка

Tags: java

Как сделать, чтобы переменная count увеличивалася до тех пор, пока файл удачно не сохранится? Также проблемой является, что обязательно нужно обрабатывать ошибки (IDEA заставляет). Был вариант с `do while`, но что-то не получилось.

```
int count = 0;

try (InputStream in = new URL(text).openStream()){
                Files.copy(in, Paths.get("D:/Program/image" + "_" + count + ".jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                count++;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `while`. Но я бы на вашем месте добавил ограничение на количество попыток.

Можно также оптимизировать нагрузку на сеть: скачать стрим в массив байтов, а потом создавать из этого массива потоки и пытаься сохранять их.

Но вообще, оптимальней найти 1-й подходящий файл, и сохранять уже в него.

В коде привел пример без оптимизаций:

```java
    private static void save(URL url, String dir) throws AccessDeniedException {
        int attempt = 0;
        boolean isError = true;
        while (isError) {
            try (InputStream in = url.openStream()) {
                String path = dir + "Image_" + attempt + ".jpg";
                Files.copy(in, Paths.get(path));
                isError = false;
            }
            // нужно для избежания бесконечного цикла
            catch (AccessDeniedException ade) {
                throw ade;
            }
            // если файл уже существует (java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException), или если не удалось записать
            catch (IOException e) {
                attempt++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Пример вызова:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String dir = "/home/mikhail/";
        URL url = new URL("https://kinsta.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/jpg-vs-jpeg.jpg");
        save(url, dir);
    }
```

Comment: Я запустил ваш код, но приложение падает с каким-то `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Comment: рискну предположить, что Java не поняла, что функция с хвостовой рекурсией... Сейчас подумаю

Comment: @АртёмОконечников исправил. Это не должно привести к переполнению стека. Но если, например, директория будет не валидна, или нет прав на запись, программа будет выполняться бесконечно (хотя процессор не просядет).

Comment: "или нет прав на запись" - SecurityException должен вылезти

Comment: стоило бы проверять файл на существование перед попыткой записи методом Files.exists

Comment: @DmitryTerentjev вроде должна. Но у меня при записи в `/root/` вылетает [`java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/AccessDeniedException.html), которая наследуется от `FileSystemException`, а та от `IOException`

Comment: @DmitryTerentjev "стоило бы проверять файл на существование". наверно. Надо уточнить у автора вопроса

Comment: @MikhailIonkin "вылетает java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException" это же хорошо, его тоже можно перехватывать вместе с SecurityException

Comment: @DmitryTerentjev добавил обработку AccessDeniedException. Не думаю, что в рамках данной функции можно корректно обработать SecurityException

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103438/discussion-between-mikhail-ionkin-and-dmitry-terentjev).